# Event-driven architecture design problem with Eventbridge and cross-stack references?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, event-driven-design, serverless-architecture, aws-event-bridge

I have a question that I have been thinking about for the last few days.

[This is the diagram of a part of the architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du6RX.png)

I am concerned about the scalability and maintainability of this approach. We are discovering the first problems that are giving us headaches.

The main problem we are having is with the updates of the stacks or when deleting them during the development process.

Thanks a lot

Comment: "main problem" - what exactly is the problem? Any error messages?

Comment: Hello @Marcin, thanks for your reply. There is actually no problem, but there might be in the future when updating or deleting stacks with circular cross stack references. The increased number of references may cause problems when the stacks involved have to be modified.